# Need help choosing compatible rear derailleur, cassette & chain

Tags: chain, derailleur, chainring, drivetrain, replacement

I just "inherited" a bike that has no rear derailleur or chain.  It also looks like the cassette is pretty worn, so I'm thinking about replacing that too.  I've looked around on the forum and I think I'm on the right track, but I'd love to hear from someone who knows what they're talking about (I don't).  Here are the specs...

- Front chain ring - RaceFace 22-32-42
- Front Derailleur - shimano XTR (at least 10 years old)
- Shifters - Shimano xtr (also old)
- Current rear cassette - Shimano hyperglide - 12-32 8 speed - worn and looks ready to be replaced

Here what I'd like to buy. I chose it mostly because it's inexpensive.  I'm trying to do this for under $100.

- Shimano HG 51 cassette 11-32T
- Shimano CN HG50 Chain
- Shimano Alivio RD-M410

I've read on the forum that the chain and cassette are compatible - I just want to make sure that all these bits and pieces work with the other parts on my bike.

Comment: Before you invest in this bike, you might want to look around for another used bike that has all its parts.

Answer (score 1):

Everything there looks like it should work together all right. If you are replacing the drive train components here, you may want to get new cabling for the shifters as well.

Any 6/7/8 speed chain should be fine on this setup. The cassettes also seem equivalent.

I'd worry about the condition of the old shifters due to the age, they should be compatible though. However, Alivio rapid fire shifters can be had relatively cheap you need to replace them if anything is wrong with the old shifters.  The original XTR stuff was definitively higher quality when new.

Comment: Thanks Benzo for the suggestion about the cabling for the shifters.  I'll look in to it for sure.

Comment: And thanks to Daniel too - yes, I thought about getting a different bike but the total for the parts is under $90 so far.